# Triggers, commands not firing in custom ListBox's ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, events, listbox, custom-controls, listboxitem

I've got a custom ListBox control with a style set up in my Themes/Generic.xaml. I then have a button in the ListBox's ItemTemplate, and it's Click event isn't firing and I've got no idea why. Same goes for the button's Commands (I'm confident the Command issue isn't DataContext related) and interaction triggers. While attempting to debug, I noticed that using the default ListBox instead of my own stopped the problem, but I need to use the custom control.

This is essentially what I've got (fluff removed for brevity). The button:

```
<controls:CustomListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Click=MyHandler/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</controls:CustomListBox>
```

And the custom control's style in Themes/Generic:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomListBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomListBox}">
        <Border>
          <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
          </ScrollViewer>
         </Border>
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
 </Style>
```

How can I get this event to fire?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should probably be a usercontrol rather than a custom control.

Are you really going to change the template out of this for something else?

If you use an event handler like that then how are you planning on using the delegate?  It's a very inflexible way of working you're headed in.

You mentioned command, which is probably rather more like it.

If you use a button in an item template with a command bound like

```
 <Button Command="{Binding RowCommand}"
```

Then the datacontext of that Button is the content of the row.

If you bind ItemsSource to a collection Items of ItemVM then it's looking in the ItemVM that is presented to that row.

Comment: I made it a custom control so I could apply filtering on the item source, similar to how if you type ".R" on a list in VS, ".Reverse()" might show up. Not sure what you mean by changing the template out for something else. There's a little more to my ControlTemplate than what I showed above, but I think I do need that for styling the control the way I want. For how I plan on using the delegate/handler, the sender/EventArg arguments give me all I need to perform the logic I want when the button is pressed.

Comment: I had a command working, but as mentioned, only when I replaced the custom control with the default ListBox in my xaml. This is why I suspect it wasn't a DataContext issue. For  now, I'm using a PreviewMouseDown event on the button and that's working. So maybe for some reason the click event was getting handled somewhere it shouldn't have, although I saw nothing that would cause this anywhere with my custom control.

Comment: When you click on a listbox item that item is selected. The process which does that handles that mouse clicking. You'd have to put something inside the row if you wanted to handle a click event.

Comment: I'm clicking on a button in the ListBoxItem's ItemTemplate, which isn't selecting the ListBoxItem (I have a SelectionChanged handler attached and it's not firing when I click the button, which is what I want).

Comment: Then bind isselected twoway and set isselected on the row viewmodel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55780718/handling-the-same-click-event-in-a-nested-control-inside-listboxitem-datatemplat/55783885?noredirect=1#comment98269174_55783885